# drupal 7 - drupal_add_js - inline doesn't execute

Tags: javascript

I made a custom module and I added the following code inside the php tag and also in my hook_menu function

`drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');`

I can't figure out why it's not firing.

When I look at the 'view source' of the page
I do see this:

`<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });
//--><!]]>
</script>`

Comment: You just added it right inside of the <?php tag? Best practice would be to wrap it in a mymodule_init(){ ... } function.

Comment: Ok, just added it to my mymodule_init()....But still nothing..:(

Answer (score 2):

Go through this document http://drupal.org/node/171213 It shows how to use Jquery. The syntax for jquery ready function is:

```
jquery(document).ready(function($) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Comment: :(, i added the $ to the function argument...still nothing

Comment: damn.......all this time, I had to clear cache ...F******

Comment: that's quite frustrating when you are learning

Comment: it's quite annoying to always having to clear cache :(

Comment: You need to clear cache every time when you make changes :)